# Non-strict vs. strict OR-operator

Tags: haskell, boolean, evaluation, strict, or-operator

This one is fairly simple, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer anywhere else.
It's about a strict vs. a non-strict operator, in this case a simple OR.

Have I understood correctly that with a strict operator, you ALWAYS have to look at the second of two Boolean values, like this:

`strict_or False True = True`
`strict_or True False = True`
and so on?

How about the non_strict operator, does this one **always** only look at the first value, or does it require 2 True values for returning True?

i.e. `or True False = True` vs. `or True False = False`?

The way it looks now, there are still some logical mistakes in my code:

```
or' :: (Bool,Bool) -> Bool
or' (True, True) = True
or' (True, False) = False
or' (False, _) = False


strict_or :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool
strict_or (True,True) = True
strict_or (False, True) = True
strict_or (False, False) = False
strict_or (True, False) = True
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something big, `or'` does not appear to act like an OR at all - it has the behavior of an AND. While the evaluation style is different between strict and non-strict OR, the truth-table semantics (assuming both arguments are valid booleans) should be identical.

Comment: Yes, that's what I gathered as well, hence I said that I have some mistakes in my logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether you have a strict or non-strict `or` it always gives the same answer given the same boolean values, so

```
True  or True  -> True
False or True  -> True
True  or False -> True
False or False -> False
```

The only case where the strictness matters is that if you have an expression `A or B` where the `B` sub-expression might a) take a long time (or even forever!) to calculate or b) potentially throw an exception.

A strict `or` will always run the potentially long calculation whereas a non-strict `or` can "short circuit" if the first parameter is `True` and hence never evaluate the second parameter at all. This also means that if the second sub-expression throws an exception when it's evaluated you'll get a boolean table like this for strict `or`:

```
True  or <exception> -> <exception>
False or <exception> -> <exception>
```

But for non-strict `or` you'll have

```
True  or <exception> -> True
False or <exception> -> <exception>
```

Note that all of the above assumes that the non-strict `or` is non-strict over its second parameter (like it is in Haskell and most other programming languages) but you could also have a non-strict `or` that is non-strict for its first parameter.

Comment: So, when coding it, non-strict uses `True _ = True` and strict always looks at both values?

Comment: However `False True` on non-strict should also return True, when I have understood everything correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Non-strict functions only evaluate operands if they need to. Thus, a non-strict OR won't evaluate the second operand IF the first operand is found to be true. (Because the result will be true regardless of what the second operand is.)

Comment: So the strict operator is the one who **requires** two True values to return true?

Comment: No, neither version of `or` requires two True values. That would be an `and`.

Comment: @dschib The real difference lies in `or True undefined`, which is `True` for the lazy version and raises an error for the strict one. The behaviour for "normal" (not bottom) values should be the same, however, as by the definition of disjunction.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought one of the `or`s would only look at the first value and, if that one is `True`, automatically return `True` and the same for `False`?

Comment: I added my current code into the post. Exceptions don't have to be handled.